# How to pass Data object in Post Api in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, byte

I am new in swift and trying to send Data to Api which is in the form of Data object and i am trying to pass that data in JSON

```
let val:Data = myFile.DataRepresentation()



let json: [String: Any] = ["file": val,
                       "dict": ["1":"First", "2":"Second"]]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
```

it giving me error "Invalid type in JSON.write"

or help me how can i pass Data in NSMUtableURLRequest

Comment: `(NS)Data` is invalid in JSON. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization or better https://www.json.org/ Check what is expecting the API. There could be different way: base64, etc. Are you really looking for JSON? Maybe you are interested in multipart requests.

Comment: @Larme actually i was working with multipart, in multipart have problem to to send multiple values with parameters, which need to send in 1 value as separation with boundaries. but my server is not handling boundaries. so need to send data in bytes

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this code example, it should work:

```
let json: [String: Any] = ["name": "morpheus",
                           "job": "leader"]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

// create post request
let url = URL(string: "https://reqres.in/api/users")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// insert json data to the request
request.httpBody = jsonData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        print(responseJSON)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: i was to pass Data object to api

Comment: I don't know if you can convert a data object to json. The json is a text file. Can you explain more precisely what you would like to do? Does the variable "val" with represent?

Comment: i have an object which i PDFDocument, i have to send that file on server in bytes

Comment: Can you share the documentation of your API? With this little information it is difficult to help you.